# I can not pass a PHP SESSION and write it to text

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to pass `$_POST` info as `$_SESSION` but when it doesn't work, I don't know what is wrong in my code.

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['nombre'] = $_POST['nombre'];
$_SESSION['edad']   = $_POST['edad'];

?>
<html>
<form action="accion.php" method="post">
 <p>Name: <input type="text" name="nombre" /></p>
 <p>Age: <input type="text" name="edad" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
</html>
```

Second file

```
<?php
        session_start(); 
        if(isset($_SESSION['nombre']) && isset($_SESSION['edad'])) {
            $data = $_SESSION['nombre'] . '-' . $_POST['edad'] . "\n";
            $ret = file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
            if($ret === false) {
                die('There was an error writing this file');
            }
            else {
                echo "$ret bytes written to file";
            }
        }
        else {
           die('no post data to process');
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Now check your question again and answer honestly: do you seriously think what you posted can be answered?

Comment: So is this 2 files? Please make it a little more clear.

Comment: You appear to be setting the `$_SESSION` data on the same page as your form, without checking that the information is set. Though it is admittedly rather unclear as to what code is on what page.

Comment: I think you need to check that $_POST is set or not before loading it to $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will solve your problem:

File1.php

```
<html>
<form action="File2.php" method="post">
 <p>Name: <input type="text" name="nombre" /></p>
 <p>Age: <input type="text" name="edad" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
</html>
<?php
echo $_GET['msg'];
?>
```

File2.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['edad'])) {
        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $_POST['nombre'];
        $_SESSION['edad']   = $_POST['edad'];
        $data = $_SESSION['nombre'] . '-' . $_POST['edad'] . "\n";
        $ret = file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        if($ret === false) {
            header("Location:File1.php?msg=There was an error writing this file");
        }
        else {
            header("Location:File1.php?msg=$ret bytes written to file";
        }
    }
    else {
       header("Location:File1.php?msg=no post data to process");
    }
?>
```

When the form is submitted, it is submitted to File2.php

So, your first session being set and taking values as POST from it in File1.php won't work.

The best option is to set the session in the second file and then give back a message to the File1.php as shown above.

Comment: I don't know why, but it gives me back a "no post data to process", and the input is not saved in the txt. Thank you.

Comment: Is the above file named accion.php by you or anything else?

Comment: Check the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code bellow. It is better to start `session` once at the begining of the file and check if `post` variable contains value to set in the `session`.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['edad'])) {
  $_SESSION['nombre'] = $_POST['nombre'];
  $_SESSION['edad']   = $_POST['edad'];
}

?>
<html>
<form action="accion.php" method="post">
 <p>Name: <input type="text" name="nombre" /></p>
 <p>Age: <input type="text" name="edad" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
</html>


<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['nombre']) && isset($_SESSION['edad'])) {
        $data = $_SESSION['nombre'] . '-' . $_POST['edad'] . "\n";
        $ret = file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        if($ret === false) {
            die('There was an error writing this file');
        }
        else {
            echo "$ret bytes written to file";
        }
    }
    else {
       die('no post data to process');
    }
?>
```

If you want to send the form in the same page instead using `action="action.php"` use `action=""`

Comment: I don't know why, but it gives me back a "no post data to process", and the input is not saved in the txt.

Comment: Did you tried change your form? Like `<form action="" method="post">` this.

Comment: Sorry, I forget that! Now it works! Thank you. How can I check multiple  $_POST variable for existence using isset()?

Comment: You can use `foreach` loop for that.

Comment: if (isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
$MESSAGE .= "<font style='color:#9c0000;'>|</font> [Client Number]  = <font style='color:#0070ba;'>".$_SESSION['cliente']."</font><br>\n";}  do you anything wrong there?

Comment: I think you got your answer already. And where the block of code come from in your last comment?